# Excel VBA - Change cell color based on value

Tags: excel, vba

In the table in the indicated range, I would like to mark the cell with the value in white, and the other cells with no value in gray. I have code but it doesn't produce any result. There is no error either. What to change to make it work

```
For Each cell In wbMe.Sheets("page3").Range("B76:K89")
If cell.Value = "Yes" Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 10
If cell.Value = "No" Then cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
   Next cell
```

[image]

Comment: Try Conditional Formatting, please.

Comment: First, `Cell.Value` will be "87 597" or "723", not "Yes".  Second, why not use [Conditional Formatting](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/use-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-information-fed60dfa-1d3f-4e13-9ecb-f1951ff89d7f)?

Comment: Since numbers can be different, not always the same, I mean more about the fact that there will be any values

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of what your expected output should look like?

Comment: In the screenshot you provided, there are numbers in the cells. The code checks for strings `Yes` or `No`.

Comment: @Gangula  My point is that if another macro completes the fields in this table and it can be different, it would mark the fields with values in white and leave blank in gray

Comment: check for empty value `cell.value = vbnullstring` - but conditional formatting makes much more sense - especially if user/code might change the values

Comment: I don't think your question is clear to anyone. Its better if you could edit it and add more details so that you can get the right answer from folks.

Comment: Why not use length of cell? if it's >0 then white else grey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this code

```
Sub SetColor()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B7")
    
    Dim white As Long
    white = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    
    Dim grey As Long
    grey = RGB(200, 200, 200)
    
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In r
        If c.Value2 = 1 Then c.Interior.Color = white
        If c.Value2 = 0 Then c.Interior.Color = grey
      
    Next

End Sub
```

As Ike mentions for Empty values you can use this

```
Sub SetColor()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("B2:B7")
    
    Dim white As Long
    white = RGB(255, 255, 255)
    
    Dim grey As Long
    grey = RGB(200, 200, 200)
    
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In r
        If IsEmpty(c.Value2) Then
            c.Interior.Color = white
            'OR
            'c.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
        Else
            c.Interior.Color = grey
      End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I don't think this will work - you have to check for empty not for a number.

Comment: @Ike its not working :(

Comment: Please read [It's not working](https://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)

Answer (score 4):

Please, **run** the next code. It will automatically place conditional formatting in the range you need:

```
Sub makeCondFormatting()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, cond1 As FormatCondition, cond2 As FormatCondition
  Set sh = ActiveSheet
  Set rng = sh.Range("B76:K89")
  With rng
     .FormatConditions.Delete
     Set cond1 = .FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & rng.cells(1, 1).Address(0, 0) & " <> """"")
     Set cond2 = .FormatConditions.Add(xlExpression, Formula1:="=" & rng.cells(1, 1).Address(0, 0) & "  = """"")
  End With
  With cond1
        .Interior.color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
  End With
  With cond2
        .Interior.color = RGB(197, 198, 198)
  End With
End Sub
```

It will make the range cells change their interior color automatically when the cell is empty, or not.

Comment: Much better option!